# How should an snmp client receive responses from multiple snmp agents?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I require to send get requests/ receive responses to several snmp agents from a single client/manager process.
I have implemented client/agent based on below urls:
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/ http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/creating-snmp-agent-server-in-java-using-snmp4j/

In order to send a request to an agent, the following is carried out for each server:

```
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
snmp = new Snmp(transport);
transport.listen();
...
pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
// communityTarget contains server target address.
ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, communityTarget, null);
```

In order to receive responses from the servers, do I require to carry out a separate transport.listen() for each server? or create
a new TransportMapping and Snmp object for each server?

I don't understand how the client process can know which server returned the response? ...since
each time transport.listen() is called, the listening port address (transport.getListenAddress()) is the same. 
and 1 extra udp port is listed (netstat).

I am intending to poll each server from a different background thread (in order that the polling interval can be configured).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same transport mapping.

From the example you provided, it seems that you are using the synchronous API.

The response is just from the agent you sent the request too.

In any case, you can get the peer (agent) address from `ResponseEvent.getPeerAddress`

http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/event/ResponseEvent.html#getPeerAddress()

Comment: With the synchronous api, am I right in thinking that if I send requests/responses from different threads, sending a snmp synchronous request/response from 1 thread shall not block the synchronous request/response from another thread? i.e. they can be sent concurrently?

Comment: That's correct. Each thread acts independently. SNMP4J is thread safe http://www.snmp4j.org/html/faq.html